# AES and RSA encryption in iOS and JAva

Tags: java, ios, aes, rsa

Has any one got a chance to work on RSA and AES in Java as well as in iOS.
Basically i want to pass public key to Java platform from iOS and vice versa.

Let me know if any one has already worked on this and got a solution.

Chilkat is the helpful library i agree but it s costing around 180$.
Let me know some useful links if you find.

Regards,
Bhat

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to know. Do you know how to send/receive packets on iOS and Java platforms? If you do, just send the public RSA key, you don't need to encrypt it because it can be public. Then encrypt AES key using public RSA key, send it through internet and decrypt the AES key with private RSA key on the other device, then just use the AES key for further encryption.

Comment: As you know Public key has modulus and exponent keys, i am trying to pass these values between java and objective c and later trying to generate public key using these keys. Once public keys are generated am trying to encrypt the sting using this public key in ios . This encrypted string is getting decrypted at java end, however here am facing problem and java is throwing RSA Block too large exception. And am stuck here. !!!

Comment: Maybe you want to encrypt too much data with too small RSA key? When your code is throwing an exception it is good to post the code causing the problem to make it easier for other people to answer you question/find the problem.

Comment: Sure Mike :) ,send you the problem what am facing in detail.However have a look at https://devforums.apple.com/message/967676#967676.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used RNCryptor before on iphone and they have a JNCryptor for java as well. This library has worked well for me.

Comment: What is the padding info used in both the platforms ?I tried using the same but Java classes are throwing RSA block too large exception.

Comment: adrian.coroian, Could please share the sample code with me for both iOS and java ?

Comment: Raised a query in apple forum as well..link :https://devforums.apple.com/message/967676#967676

Comment: I didn't mess with any padding. I was just using encryptWithData decryptWithData functions that are part of the library. The github page has sample code which shows how that stuff works.

Comment: RNCryptor and JNCryptor is for  AES Encryptor/Decryptor.Need help in RSA algos

Comment: https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-Certificate--Key--and-Trust-Sample-Project

Comment: Let see how this can help me out.. Thanks Adrian :)